# Take action with empathy

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word that mean taking action based on understanding how someone feels?

Comment: There is a difference between "how someone feels", and "empathy". You may want to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

[Considerate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/considerate), [Perceptive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perceptive) are some words which fit your description

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is called either, Empathy or Compassion[list of empathy statements](http://lifecoachbloggers.blogspot.in/2014/05/empathy-statements-examples-list.html)